# Grunt replace last occurrence of matching string

Tags: regex, gruntjs

I have a custom requirement where I need to replace the last occurrence of of a closing brace with empty string,

How can i achieve using Grunt-replace ?

In the below Templates.js file I am replacing

```
    angular.module('abc.templates', []).run(
with 
return
```

Templates.js

Now I have to remove the unnecessary closing brace at line:20 below.

```
 angular.module('abc.templates', []).run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
      $templateCache.put("test",
          //
          //
          //
      $templateCache.put("test",
          //
          //
          //
      $templateCache.put("test",
          //
          //
          //
      $templateCache.put("test",
        //
        //
        //
 line 20:   }]);
```

In the above Templates.js file I want to remove the last occurence of closing brace ')' at line 20 mentioned above.

Can someone help me with any regex or some other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace) you could try the following configuration:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    replace: {
      templateJs: {
        options: {
          usePrefix: false,
          patterns: [
            {
              match: /angular\.module\('abc\.templates', \[\]\)\.run\(/g,
              replacement: 'return '
            },
            {
              match: /(angular\.module\('abc\.templates', \[\]\)\.run\([\w\W]+?}])(\))(;)/g,
              replacement: '$1$3'
            }
          ]
        },
        files: [
          // Define your paths as necessary...
          {expand: true, flatten: true, src: ['src/template.js'], dest: 'build/'}
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-replace');
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'replace:templateJs');
};
```

---

**Additional info**

1. The first `match` regex pattern used in the `patterns` Array is explained [here](https://regex101.com/r/9dRWHx/1). This handles the first part of replacing `angular.module('abc.templates', []).run(` with `return`
2. The second `match` regex pattern used in the `patterns` Array is explained [here](https://regex101.com/r/9dRWHx/3/). This removes the closing brace `)` from `}]);` to end up with `}];`

---

**Note**: The second regex will match the first instance of the characters `}]);` after the initial `angular.module('abc.templates', []).run(` part and remove the `)` from it. So, unfortunately if the pattern `}]);` occurs elsewhere in the body of your function this will not meet your requirement. Otherwise it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for you response, it helped me.